# Assign javascript to certain element and its children

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below structure to a website:

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="main-content profile1 left">
      <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {Message.initialMessageList(1);});
      </script>
      <div class="message-menu">
          <div class="message"></div>
      <div>
   </div>
   <div class="main-content profile2 left">
      <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {Message.initialMessageList(2);});
      </script>
      <div class="message-menu">
          <div class="message"></div>
      <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What i need is for in my Message javascript object to make reference to the elements that are a child of the profile depending on which profile id was passed (1 or 2).

ie when 1 is passed we should be referencing to the div message-menu that is a child of profile1 div and ignore the message-menu that is a child of profile2.

Part of the javascript currently:

```
var Message = {
    searchTimeout: null,

    initialMessageList: function(profile_id) {
        var messageContent = document.getElementsByClassName('main-content profile'+ profile_id);
        var messagelist = messageContent[0].getElementsByClassName('messages-list');

        messagelist[0].innerhtml = '<div class="message-loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';

        Message.fetchMessageList(profile_id,  Message.initialMessageListHandler);
    },

    initialMessageListHandler: function(data, profile_id) {
        $('.messages-list .message-loader').remove();
        $('.messages-list').html(Message.getMessageListHtml(data));
        Message.bindMessageList();
        $('.open-message').first().click();
    },
```

What I am really looking for is aw ay to set a global variable for all the functions to know which childs element they should be referring to without having to keep passing the profile ID about in the javascript.

Comment: If it number based could you not use a for loop? or are you looking to get rid of the numbers as that is ur current solution?. you could use a _map_ like solution where u just keep a reference to a variable and a property that stores arguments to be passed to the mapped function reference

Comment: If you would pass the messageContent instead of the profile_id, you could just make all referring to that element instead. So you would always have it as root container. For example:
messageContent[0].profile_id = profile_id;
Message.fetchMessageList(messageContent[0],  Message.initialMessageListHandler);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since I do not know what your code is supposed to do, just to answer your primary question: Instead of passing the profile_id you could pass the container.

```
initialMessageList: function(profile_id) {
    var messageContent = document.getElementsByClassName('main-content profile'+ profile_id)[0];
    messageContent.profile_id = profile_id; //We can keep it just in case:

    var messagelist = messageContent.getElementsByClassName('messages-list');
    messagelist[0].innerhtml = '<div class="message-loader"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>';

    //Message.fetchMessageList(profile_id,  Message.initialMessageListHandler);
    Message.fetchMessageList(messageContent, Message.initialMessageListHandler); //We pass the container instead of the profile_id and have both in the end.
}
```